# Jetpack Compose LaunchedEffect confusing

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

`LaunchedEffect` changes in `value` is the implementation of `println`

But why it is also executed when entering the default `value` for the first time, it is really confusing, why is it designed like this.

```kotlin
LaunchedEffect(value) {
    println("--1--")
}
```

How to avoid first execution？

Answer (score 7):

You can just make your **custom effect** like this **UpdateEffect**:

```kotlin
/**
 * The same as [LaunchedEffect] but skips the first invocation
 */
@Composable
fun UpdateEffect(key: Any, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
    var isTriggered by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LaunchedEffect(key) {
        if (isTriggered) {
            block()
        } else {
            isTriggered = true
        }
    }
}
```

And then replace your `LaunchedEffect` with `UpdateEffect`.

Comment: yes that's what i do now

Answer (score 1):

LaunchedEffect starts when the Composable enters the composition and restarts when the key(s) is changed. You can't avoid executing it, but inside you can check if it's the default value, meaning this is the first run.

```
LaunchedEffect(value) {
    if (value != defaultValue) println("--1--")
}
```

Comment: In this way, the coroutine is still started, and additional variables are required to save the default value.

Comment: `var scrollToTop = mutableStateOf(false)`
`if (scrollToTop.value) {` `LaunchedEffect(true) {` `listState.animateScrollToItem(0)` `scrollToTop.value = false` `} }` The way I use now, the outer package

Answer (score 1):

```
How to avoid first execution
```

If you want to avoid only first execution, you wrap your `LaunchedEffect(Unit)` in an `if{}` block - if this is what you want.

```
if(yourCondition){
  LaunchedEffect(){
  }
}
```

`LaunchedEffect` triggers

- during initial composition or if it's key changes
- during initial composition, which also included adding it in view-tree conditionally, even in case of re-composition.

For eg -> If you first if condition during composition added the `LaunchedEffect` in the view-tree, and if removed in further re-composition and added again (it will again be re-launched).